# Does the command switch/flag order matter when sending git commands?

Tags: windows, git, command, git-bash

The commands:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

and

```
git config --show-origin --list
```

are the same command with the switch/flag order swapped around. Both commands work on Git Bash for Windows, so obviously for some commands, when using the command with multiple switch/flags, the switch/flag order doesn't matter...

BUT

are there commands where the switch/flag order does matter?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are.  `git rev-parse` prints output in the order that the arguments appear.  So if you run `git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir --git-common-dir`, that will produce different output than `git rev-parse --git-common-dir --absolute-git-dir`.

Additionally, while some programs, including some, but not all, Git subcommands, accept options and arguments in any order, that's not guaranteed to work, and when scripting especially, you should always assume that all options must precede all non-option arguments, since this behaviour is required by POSIX.